# Matching color of HDR panorama

Tags: hdr, color-correction, tone-mapping

For normal images color checkers can be used to correct images that the color representation is euqual.
How is it done with HDR images? How can color checker board measurements be included in the tone-mapping process?

Comment: Software or gear recommendations are off-topic here, so you should [edit] this question and focus on the first part; the hows and whys of colour correction with HDR images.

Comment: Changed the question, although generally speaking this question will be probably answered with a specific algorithm -> as it is a question in this direction. Therefore the request for software is not really far away.

Comment: Look for a paper, "Colorimetric calibration of high dynamic range images with a ColorChecker chart", D. Varghese, R. Wanat and R.K. Mantiuk